How do I maintain full file path but only display basename in a sortable python listbox?
I am trying to only display the basename of a file in a python listbox but maintain the full file path somehow. I know how to only display the base file name but the problem is the listbox is sortable and when I try to perform the next step of the program (printing out the files to pdf) it can't find the files in the list because they don't have a full file path. If I display the full file path in the listbox it works but I'd prefer to only see the filename.
Code is below. I have removed most of the functionality to just focus on what I am asking.
The code below will open a tk box. Click "Individual Sort" button. Choose any image files. In the new window click "Save List". The goal is for this to print the original file path of the image but it currently prints the path that the program is in. If you comment/uncomment the labeled lines it will work but the list will display the full file path.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

ws = Tk()
ws.title('Select Files to Import')
ws.geometry('500x200')
ws.config(bg='#456')

f = ('sans-serif', 13)
btn_font = ('sans-serif', 10)
bgcolor = '#BF5517'

def sort():
    global second
    second = Toplevel()
    second.geometry('800x400')
    menubar=Menu(second)
    menubar.add_command(label="Save List", command=save)
    second.config(menu=menubar)
    global listbox
    listbox = Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(second)
    listbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    directory = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    n = 0
    for file in directory:        
        listbox.insert(n, os.path.basename(file))   ####comment
        #listbox.insert(n, file)                    ####uncomment
        n=n+1
 
def save():
  image=listbox.get(0, listbox.size())
  for x in image:
      print(os.path.abspath(x))

class Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(tk.Listbox):
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    kw['selectmode'] = tk.SINGLE
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.getState, add='+')
    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.setCurrent, add='+')
    self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.shiftSelection)
  def setCurrent(self, event):
    self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)
  def getState(self, event):
    i = self.nearest(event.y)
    self.curState = self.selection_includes(i)
  def shiftSelection(self, event):
    i = self.nearest(event.y)
    if self.curState == 1:
      self.selection_set(self.curIndex)
    else:
      self.selection_clear(self.curIndex)
    if i < self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      selected = self.selection_includes(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i+1, x)
      if selected:
        self.selection_set(i+1)
      self.curIndex = i
      x = self.get(i)
      selected = self.selection_includes(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i-1, x)
      if selected:
        self.selection_set(i-1)
      self.curIndex = i

frame = Frame(ws, padx=20, pady=20, bg=bgcolor)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

btn_frame = Frame(frame, bg=bgcolor)
btn_frame.grid(columnspan=2, pady=(50, 0))

sort_btn = Button(
    btn_frame,
    text='Individual Sort',
    command=sort,
    font=btn_font,
    padx=10, 
    pady=5
)
sort_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, padx=(5,5))

ws.mainloop()


Have you considered just storing the base names and their associated paths as key:value pairs in a dictionary? That way you can use the keys as the Listbox entries and still have them easily associated to other values.

Also, as an aside, you don't need import tkinter as tk and from tkinter import * - generally you should just use the first one and prefix things with tk.

Based on the code, all files are from same folder, so you can simply store the folder name as an attribute of the listbox.

I appreciate the responses. I didn't include it in my original code but I have functionality for the user to add files from multiple folders. I tried to implement this solution but am having an issue with the directory being overwritten.

I am looking into using a dictionary. I think an issue is that there will be multiple values (files) for a the same key (folder). I know how to save multiple values to the same key but am having an issue later with finding a key for a given value. It is saying the value is not in the list even though I see that it is. I think it is because of the duplicate keys. I am still working with this.

It is hard to do what you want when using Listbox widget.  However you can use ttk.Treeview to simulate a Listbox which can achieve what you want:

create a single column ttk.Treeview without heading
insert the full pathname in text option and the filename in the single column values option

Then you can get all the full pathnames by retrieving the text option of each row.
Below is a simple example:
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, show='', columns=('col',), selectmode='browse')
        self.column('col', width=200) # set it to whatever you want
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self._start_drag)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self._on_drag)

    def _start_drag(self, event):
        selected = self.identify_row(event.y)
        if selected:
            self.selection_set(selected)

    def _on_drag(self, event):
        row = self.identify_row(event.y)
        if row:
            idx = self.index(row)
            for s in self.selection():
                self.move(s, '', idx)

    def insert(self, index, path):
        path = Path(path)
        # text option to store the full path
        # values option to show the filename only
        super().insert('', index, text=path, values=(path.name,))

    @property
    def values(self):
        return [self.item(row, 'text') for row in self.get_children()]

def save():
    for x in listbox.values:
        print(x)

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10, expand=1, fill='both')

# insert sample paths
for i in range(1, 20):
    listbox.insert('end', f'/path/to/image{i}.png')

tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=save).pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()


Thank you for all the help! I have a solution below. I used a dictionary but stored the file as key and path as value. This allowed me to get around having duplicate paths. I also used the replace function to convert the path into the proper format.
I will look into the proposed solution of using ttk.Treeview to see if this is a better solution but as of now my program is working as hoped!
Thanks again!
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import BOTH, LEFT, Button, Frame, Menu, Toplevel, filedialog
import os

ws = tk.Tk()
ws.title('Select Files to Import')
ws.geometry('500x200')
ws.config(bg='#456')

f = ('sans-serif', 13)
btn_font = ('sans-serif', 10)
bgcolor = '#BF5517'

dict = {}

def sort():
  global second
  second = Toplevel()
  second.geometry('800x400')
  menubar=Menu(second)
  menubar.add_command(label="Save List", command=save)
  menubar.add_command(label="Add Files", command=add)
  second.config(menu=menubar)
  global listbox
  listbox = Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(second)
  listbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
  directory = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
  n = 0
  for file in directory:
    key = os.path.basename(file)  
    value = os.path.dirname(file)  
    update_dict(key, value)
    listbox.insert(n, os.path.basename(file))
    n=n+1

def update_dict(key, value):
  if key in dict:
    dict[key].append(value)
  else:
    dict[key] = [value]

def add():
  directory = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
  n = 0
  for file in directory:
    key = os.path.basename(file)  
    value = os.path.dirname(file)  
    update_dict(key, value)
    listbox.insert(n, os.path.basename(file))
    n=n+1

def save():
  image=listbox.get(0, listbox.size())
  for x in image:
    string = str(dict[x]).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('/','\\').replace('\'','')
    print(string + '\\' + x)

class Drag_and_Drop_Listbox(tk.Listbox):
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
    kw['selectmode'] = tk.SINGLE
    kw['activestyle'] = 'none'
    tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.getState, add='+')
    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.setCurrent, add='+')
    self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.shiftSelection)
  def setCurrent(self, event):
    self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)
  def getState(self, event):
    i = self.nearest(event.y)
    self.curState = self.selection_includes(i)
  def shiftSelection(self, event):
    i = self.nearest(event.y)
    if self.curState == 1:
      self.selection_set(self.curIndex)
    else:
      self.selection_clear(self.curIndex)
    if i < self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      selected = self.selection_includes(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i+1, x)
      if selected:
        self.selection_set(i+1)
      self.curIndex = i
    elif i > self.curIndex:
      x = self.get(i)
      selected = self.selection_includes(i)
      self.delete(i)
      self.insert(i-1, x)
      if selected:
        self.selection_set(i-1)
      self.curIndex = i

frame = Frame(ws, padx=20, pady=20, bg=bgcolor)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

btn_frame = Frame(frame, bg=bgcolor)
btn_frame.grid(columnspan=2, pady=(50, 0))

sort_btn = Button(
  btn_frame,
  text='Individual Sort',
  command=sort,
  font=btn_font,
  padx=10, 
  pady=5
)
sort_btn.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, padx=(5,5))

# mainloop
ws.mainloop()

